# Was this the 18 year old injured boy assassinated by Israeli forces in a hospital, and the person laying on the bed on the now bloody pillow?

Tags: israel-hamas-war

An Israeli commando unit recently raided the hospital and assassinated three injured people getting care. This is [well covered in the media](https://www.reuters.com/world/this-is-moment-israeli-commandos-disguised-palestinians-walked-into-jenin-2024-01-30/). One of the pictures taken after the raid is rather notorious  and shows a bloody pillow (shown [in the Getty Images](https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/news-photo/graphic-content-a-bullet-hole-is-pictured-on-a-pillow-news-photo/1963649382), and [a different angle in the AP article](https://apnews.com/article/israel-hamas-war-news-01-30-2024-b1ba33c7c0c5c62f85932a20c2a0bc92)).

There is a [post on Instagram by @grassrootslaw](https://www.instagram.com/grassrootslaw/reel/C2yaj7towCQ/) now that is captioned,

> grassrootslaw's profile picture
> Did you see the video where Israeli soldiers dressed up like Muslim women and doctors and stormed the hospital in the West Bank and assassinated 3 young Palestinians?⁣
>
> **Did you see the bloody pillow with the bullet hole in it?⁣**
>
> **THIS IS WHO THEY MURDERED IN THAT BED. A paralyzed CHILD named Bassel.**
>
> This video was taken just one day before Israel literally shot him in the face in his bed.

Here is a screen cap of the video,

[image: Screen shot of child in bed at hospital]

Specifically the claim of

> THIS IS WHO THEY MURDERED IN THAT BED. A paralyzed CHILD named Bassel.

Does [this Instagram post contain a video of the child murdered](https://www.instagram.com/grassrootslaw/reel/C2yaj7towCQ/). And further, was he paralyzed?

Comment: Is there any doubt? Photos of the bloody aftermath shows the same bed in the same room and older profile photos of Bassel look extremely similar to the person in the bed.

Comment: Although one can question the ethics of this operation, using words like "child" and "boy" is very misleading. An 18-year-old is of military age.